# in ios 9 with hardware keyaboard attached, keyboard will hide triggers when clicking on a text field

Tags: ios, swift

noticed that in ios 9 my keyboardWillHide event is incorrectly triggered when clicking on a textbox with hardware keyboard attached.  Did something change in ios9?  Should I somehow try to detect that the keyboard is not shown, or should I try to figure out why the keyboardWillHide notification is being called and prevent it?

```
import UIKit

class BaseTextFieldViewController: UIViewController {

    // MARK: Keyboard handling

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardWillShow:", name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardWillHide:", name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
    }

    func keyboardWillShow(sender: NSNotification) {
        if let userInfo = sender.userInfo {
            if let keyboardHeight = userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey]?.CGRectValue.size.height {
                UIView.animateWithDuration(0.25, animations: { () -> Void in
                    self.view.center = CGPointMake(self.view.center.x, self.view.center.y - keyboardHeight)
                })
            }
        }
    }

    func keyboardWillHide(sender: NSNotification) {
        if let userInfo = sender.userInfo {
            if let keyboardHeight = userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey]?.CGRectValue.size.height {
                UIView.animateWithDuration(0.25, animations: { () -> Void in
                    self.view.center = CGPointMake(self.view.center.x, self.view.center.y + keyboardHeight)
                })
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I can confirm that behaviour

Comment: I know this question is super old but I am also getting this behaviour. It's really odd. I've been searching around for a solution but I haven't found a good one. Did you come up with a solution in the end?